# not getting the right counter inside my function array

Tags: c, arrays, function

function  hot_days(), that has two parameters: the number of temperatures for the current month and an array in which the temperatures are stored. Search through the temp array and count all the days on which the noon temp exceeds 32. Return this count.

check my hot_days function in the end of the code. the icounter is not working and  i think the problem is in the x < 32.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #define HIGH 32

    //function prototypes
    void read_temps(int []);

    void hot_days(int [], int []);

    int main()
    {


        //Array
        int TempsAry[31];
        int hotAry[31];

        //sending array 
        read_temps(TempsAry);

        //sending hot array
        hot_days(TempsAry, hotAry);






    getch();
    return 0;
        }

void read_temps(int TempsAry [])
{

      // variables
        int tempnum ;
        int x = 0 ;
        int icount = 0;


        while (x < 31)

    {
        // entering temperature

        printf("Please enter today's temperature:\n ");
        scanf("%d",&tempnum);

        if (tempnum <= -500)
        {
           break;         
        } 

         TempsAry[x] = tempnum;                   
         ++x;
         icount = icount +1;
      }

        //outputting array      
        for (x = 0 ; x<icount; ++x) 
        {
        printf("%d\n",TempsAry[x]);
        }
}

 void hot_days(int TempsAry [], int hotAry [])
 {
    int x = 0 ;
    int icount = 0;

    while (x<31)
    {
          if (TempsAry[x] > HIGH)
          {
            hotAry[x] = TempsAry[x];
            ++icount;              
          }

          ++x;   
    }

    printf("%d\n", icount);  









 }
```

Comment: can you give the input and output you are getting and expecting.

Comment: Clear the buffer after you read with scanf.

Comment: am just getting a random number in the icounter variable and am expecting it to count how many temperatures are over 32.

Comment: In temps_array() function you read the temps and print that array. there temps array is having right values?

Comment: @user3483718, Please provide sample input and desired output, as well as output that you are getting.

Comment: yeah my temps array is all good. i can put as many temperatures i want  as long as it is below 31 days. in my second function my she asking us to use the numbers we got in the first array and to check if any temperature is higher then 32 and to count how many.

Comment: I tried your code, and it works quite fine. What the exact problem??
http://ideone.com/e.js/R68XwR

Answer (score 0):

You have uninitialized values in `TempsAry`. You are getting undefined behavior.

Change the line

```
int TempsAry[31];
```

to

```
int TempsAry[31] = {0};
```

which is equivalent to initializing with `TempsAry` with 31 comma separated zeros. More on that can be found at [How to initialize an array in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Comment: It's the first statement in `main`.

Comment: @user3483718 I added some more information to my answer to address your question.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in this code, its working properly. checkout the snippet at ideone.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (x < 31)

    {
        // entering temperature

        printf("Please enter today's temperature:\n ");
        scanf("%d",&tempnum);

        if (tempnum <= -500)
        {
           break;         
        }
```

here the loop breaks if you enter temprature <=-500. So if you entered value satisfying this condition as i'th temperature  then the array `temp_array[]` will have garbage values after `temp_array[i]` since they will not be assigned value. This can result in your program to give random `icount`.
So make those remaining temp_array[] values 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have a **Sight issue** with your code, If you're entering numbers less than 31, because the memory allocated for the array TempsAry[] contain raw values .So in function

void hot_days(int TempsAry [], int hotAry [])

the while loop

```
while (x<31)
{
      if (TempsAry[x] > HIGH)
      {
        hotAry[x] = TempsAry[x];
        ++icount;              
      }

      ++x;   
}
```

*compares up to 31 elements even if the number of elements is less than 31, So this also includes the garbage values in the uninitialized memory, so the result obtained will be wrong*

**This can be eliminated by initializing the memory allocated for *TempsAry* to 0 in the main() function**

```
int TempsAry[31];
int hotAry[31];
memset(TempsAry,0x00,sizeof(TempsAry));
```